# what is currency symbol for hardhat node in metamask?

Tags: metamask, hardhat

[i am trying to enter currency symbol for hardhat network in my metmask connection.i have surfed a lot but couldnt find one.i have entered network name,chain id,rpc url correctly, just need to find out the currency symbol[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUP41.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any letter prefix with ETH e.g hardhatETH or ETH itself